# Serializing Nested foreign key objects

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

whoever is reading this, hope you're doing well.
I am creating a social media application which includes post in it and likes and comments just like any other social media site, I am trying to send the data from my backend to front end via serializers, the problem I am getting through is I am not able to get the output of whole data but partial data. Following represents my models.py for the objects I am trying to serialize

#### models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True,blank=True)
    profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to=to_upload,default="defaultprofile.jpg")

class Post(models.Model):
    posted_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date= models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time=models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    media=models.ImageField(default=None,blank=True,upload_to=to_upload_post)

class Like(models.Model):
    Liked_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="likes")
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and the serializers that I'm using is

#### serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['id','username','first_name','last_name','profile_picture']

class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Liked_by=UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model=Like
        fields=['Liked_by']

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posted_by=UserSerializer()
    likes=LikeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=['posted_by','id','content','date','time','media','likes']
```

This does not raise any errors while importing it but it doesn't give complete data.

The output I'm getting is

```
 {
   'posted_by': 
              OrderedDict([
                           ('id', 7), 
                           ('username', 'user'), 
                           ('first_name', ''), 
                           ('last_name', ''), 
                           ('profile_picture', '/media/defaultprofile.jpg')]), 
  'id': 4, 
  'content': 'This is a test post for likes', 
  'date': '2020-10-22', 
  'time': '05:34:55.979863', 
  'media': None
}
```

but what I'm trying to get is

#### Desired Output

```
{
   'posted_by': 
              OrderedDict([
                           ('id', 7), 
                           ('username', 'user'), 
                           ('first_name', ''), 
                           ('last_name', ''), 
                           ('profile_picture', '/media/defaultprofile.jpg')]), 
  'id': 4, 
  'content': 'This is a test post for likes', 
  'date': '2020-10-22', 
  'time': '05:34:55.979863', 
  'media': None
  'likes':
          ['Liked_by':
                     OrderedDict([
                           ('id', 1), 
                           ('username', 'user1'), 
                           ('first_name', ''), 
                           ('last_name', ''), 
                           ('profile_picture', '/media/defaultprofile.jpg')
]
)
  
}
```

Any leads or help or any strategy recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) the same way you did for Liked_by field:

```
post=models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
```

Unfortunately some exceptions are masked by django rest framework as it tries to catch some of them including `AttributeError` to perform field existence checks.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but how can I refer to the post as likes? as the likes are just a relationship of posts?

Comment: It seems related name here is confusing. Please note that by specifying related name you are telling Django what to call the relation from the other way hand. You are telling Django to put a field in any post object named `likes` to refer to the related likes. I also put a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note:

1. serializers work on data, not serializer classes. Instead, you need to create SerializerMethodField() and create a getter for it.
2. To avoid issue with spamming database with requests remember to add .select_related() / .prefetch_related() to your QuerySet.
3. It's considered a good practice to user lowercase field names :)

example:

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Liked_by = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model=Like
        fields=['Liked_by']
    
    def get_Liked_by(self, instance):
        return UserSerializer(instance.Liked_by, many=False).data
```